# crontab, schedule jobs to run in a sequence in the shortest time

Tags: performance, scheduled-tasks, cron

supose 3 jobs that run in a sequence,

```
jobA  -->  jobB  -->  jobC
~20min     ~25min      ~5m
```

one should execute when the previous finishes. individual duration time might vary, although a reasonable duration is known..
to keep this process in an execution loop can be done with `crontab`, but how to optimize it in order to run the sequence as fast as possible? 
the jobs/process do not directly communicate.

At the moment I've this 3 jobs scheduled in crontab, so jobA start at minute 0, jobB at minute 30 and jobC at minute 40. But in most cases jobB and jobC could start earlier.

The idea is to run this sequence once per hour, as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Cron executes the commands with shell. It is then enough to run one long command like this.

```
jobA && jobB && jobC
```

Using `&&` will run `jobB` only if `jobA` succeededs.

Scheduling those jobs independently does not guarantee that A finishes before B or C before B.

Answer (score 1):

One way -- create a single script: driver.shl:

```
/path/to/JobA [parameters]
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo 'error' | mailx -s 'job JobA failed ' me@mycompany.com
/path/to/JobB [parameters]
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo 'error' | mailx -s 'job JobB failed ' me@mycompany.com
/path/to/JobC [parameters]
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   echo 'error' | mailx -s 'job JobC failed ' me@mycompany.com
```

Schedule driver.shl to run once per hour in crontab.